# Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object, but the Object exists

Tags: php

**This is my class:**

```
class Network {
    protected $value = null;
    protected $properties = array();
    public $type = null;

    function __construct($value = null, $type = null) {
        $this->value = $value;
        $this->type = $type;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        if(isset($this->{$name})) {
            $this->{$name} = $value;
        } else {
            $this->properties[$name] = new self($value, null);
        }
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        return $this->properties[$name]->value;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->value;
    }
}
```

**This is what I am trying to do:**

```
$networks = new \stdClass();
$networks->test= new \Orange_Post\Network('Test');
$networks->test->enabled = true;
$networks->test->enabled->type = 'boolean';
```

**But I get the error:**

> **Warning:** Attempt to assign property of non-object on the last line, $networks->test->enabled->type = 'boolean';

This is my first attempt at branching out and doing something like this, and I just can't figure out what I am doing incorrectly.

Comment: You assigned `$networks->test->enabled = true;` so now there is no way to access the `->type` via `$networks->test->enabled->type` because you already assigned `$networks->test->enabled` to `true`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So what is going on here?

```
$networks = new \stdClass();
$networks->test= new \Orange_Post\Network('Test');
$networks->test->enabled = true;
$networks->test->enabled->type = 'boolean';
 ↑         ↑     ↑        ↑ Tries to access a property of a value ('TRUE')
 |         |     | 'enabled' as property never exists     
 |         | Is a property with an instance of '\Orange_Post\Network'
 | Is an instance of '\stdClass'
```

First off, when you try to assign `true` to the property `enabled`. Then `__set()` gets called, since the property doesn't exists.

```
public function __set($name, $value) {
    if(isset($this->{$name})) {
        $this->{$name} = $value;
    } else {
        $this->properties[$name] = new self($value, null);
    }
}
```

In that magic method you assign a new instace of the class itself to the property array `properties` and use the name (`enabled`) as index.

```
$networks->test->enabled->type = 'boolean';
```

After this you try to set a property `type` to the property `enabled`. Here `__get` gets invoked.

```
public function __get($name) {
    return $this->properties[$name]->value;
}
```

So now you simply return the array value of `properties` and return the property `value` of it. And the property `value` is not an object. Just remove the `->value` part and your code will return the object.

In other words your last line:

```
$networks->test->enabled->type = 'boolean';
```

Becomes:

```
$networks->test->properties["enabled"]->value->type = 'boolean';
                 ↑                      ↑ This is causing the problem
                 | Holds an object      | Holds 'true' as property value
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the `enabled` property a value of `true`, however the next line is trying to treat that property as an object (it's not, it's a boolean value). If you really need to have a value and type for the `enabled` property, try this instead:

```
$networks->test->enabled = new \stdClass();
$networks->test->enabled->value = true;
$networks->test->enabled->type = 'boolean';
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No. OP never has a property named `enalbed`.

Comment: You are right. I like your answer, very detailed explanation. I think the best solution would be to always return object from the __get() and access the value via a getter.